# Number of permutations for n elements with different probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I'm studying the paper [Database-friendly random projections: Johnson-Lindenstrauss with binary coins](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000003000254) by D. Achlioptas and can't manage to work out the total number of permutations with repetitions in equation (2).

To put it in context, say you want to generate 12-element long sequences composed of $\{-1, 0, +1\}$ where $\{0\}$ occurs with $p=\frac{2}{3}$ and each of $\{-1, +1\}$ with $p=\frac{1}{6}$.

For example, the following are well-formed sequences, as each is made up of 8 $\{0\}$-elements, 2 $\{-1\}$-elements and 2 $\{+1\}$-elements:

$$ 0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0 -1 -1 +1 +1 $$
$$ 0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0 -1 +1 -1 +1 $$
$$ -1 -1 +1 +1~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0 $$

How do I calculate the total number of such sequences?

If the n-elements had the same probability, their total number of r-permutations with repetitions would be $n^r = 3^{12}$, but cannot find any clear explanation of the case where they have different probabilities.

Comment: There are $3^{12}$ total number of possible sequences. Some of them have $\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{12}$ probability of occurring but that doesn't affect how many sequences there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a generalization of your question, if I understood it correctly. An alphabet $\sum$, and the probability of each symbol $a$ occurring in a word of length $n$, find out the number of such words.

Let us proceed by first calculating how many times each symbol must occur in the word. Each symbol must occur $Pr(a) \times n$ times. Then, the problem becomes the number of permutations of $n$ elements comprising $m$ classes, $n_i$ elements of class $i$ such that $\sum_{i} n_i = n$.

Hence, the number of words = $\frac{n!}{\prod_{a \in \sum} (Pr(a) \times n)!}$

So, for the given example, it is - $\frac{12!}{8! \times 4! \times 4!}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You understood precisely what I meant... the result of your solution is much smaller than $n^r$ as I expected.